# How can i add data in Realtime and display in my React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> ```
> export default function AllQuestion() {
>
>   let [allQuestion, setAllQuestion] = useState([]);
>   let isMounted = true;
>   let [userAnswer, setUserAnswer] = useState("");
>   const navigate = useNavigate();
>   const getData = () => {
>     const userId = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
>     Services.getAllQuestions(userId).then((res) => {
>       if (isMounted) {
>         console.log(res.data);
>         //-------------------Reference----------------------
>         setAllQuestion(res.data);
>       }
>     });
>   };
>   useEffect(() => {
>     getData();
>     return () => {
>       isMounted = false;
>     };
>   }, []);
>
>   const submitAnswerHandler = (qid) => {
>     console.log(qid);
>     console.log(userAnswer);
>     const uid = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
>     const name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
>     const dept = sessionStorage.getItem("department");
>     const role = sessionStorage.getItem("role");
>     const date = new Date();
>     const today =
>       date.getDay() +
>       "/" +
>       date.getMonth() +
>       "/" +
>       date.getFullYear() +
>       " at " +
>       date.getHours() +
>       ":" +
>       date.getMinutes();
>     const answerObj = {
>       userId: uid,
>       userName: name,
>       userDepartment: dept,
>       userRole: role,
>       ansDate: today,
>       answer: userAnswer,
>       quesion_id: qid,
>     };
>     //------------------Reference----------------------------
>     Services.answerQuestion(uid, qid, answerObj).then((res) => {
>       toast.success(res.data);
>       //---------------Reference------------------------ 
>       navigate('/home')
>       console.log(res.data);
>     });
>   };
>
>   return (
>     <>
>       <Header />
>       <LeftContainer />
>       <ToastContainer/>
>       <div className="right-question-div">
>         {//---------------------Reference------------------}
>         <Accordion allowZeroExpanded>
>           {allQuestion.map((question) => (
>             <AccordionItem key={question.id}>
>               <Accordion>
>                 <AccordionItemHeading>
>                   <AccordionItemButton>{question.question}</AccordionItemButton>
>                 </AccordionItemHeading>
>                 <AccordionItemPanel className="accordion__panel-cstm ">
>                   <div className="detail-heading">
>                     <u>Asked By</u>
>                   </div>
>                   <div className="detail">{question.userName}</div>
>                   <div className="detail">
>                     {question.userRole} - {question.userDepartment}
>                   </div>
>                   <div className="detail">On {question.quesDate}</div>
>                   <hr />
>                   <div>
>                     {question.answers.map((answer) => (
>                       <AccordionItemPanel
>                         className="accordion__panel-cstm "
>                         key={answer.id}
>                       >
>                         <div > {answer.answer}</div>
>
>                         <div className="detail-heading">
>                           <u>Answerd By</u>
>                         </div>
>                         <div className="detail">{answer.userName}</div>
>                         <div className="detail">
>                           {answer.userRole} - {answer.userDepartment}
>                         </div>
>                         <div className="detail">On {answer.ansDate}</div>
>                         <hr />
>                         
>                         <div></div>
>                       </AccordionItemPanel>
>                     ))}
>                   </div>
>                 </AccordionItemPanel>
>               </Accordion>
>               <Accordion className="">
>                 <AccordionItemHeading className="a-inline-block">
>                   <AccordionItemButton className="accordion__button-btn ">
>                     Answer This Question
>                   </AccordionItemButton>
>                 </AccordionItemHeading>
>                 <AccordionItemPanel>
>                   <div className="answering-div">
>                     <form className="answer-form">
>                       <div>
>                         {//----------------Reference-----------------}
>                         <textarea
>                           className="ans-box"
>                           onChange={(e) => setUserAnswer(e.target.value)}
>                         ></textarea>
>                       </div>
>                       <div>
>                         <button
>                           className="ans-btn"
>                           value={question.qid}
>                           onClick={(e) => {
>                             e.preventDefault();
>                             submitAnswerHandler(question.id);
>                             
>                           }}
>                         >
>                           Answer
>                         </button>
>                       </div>
>                     </form>
>                   </div>
>                 </AccordionItemPanel>
>               </Accordion>
>             </AccordionItem>
>           ))}
>         </Accordion>
>       </div>
>
>       <Footer />
>     </>
>   );
> }
> ```

Here on render of the above component I get all the question stored on the server side . Then I perform nested mapping in order to traverse and display the data . Also I set answers and submit it for the particular questionID . The problem I am facing is that when I post an answer I have to either reload the same component in order to get updated **allQuestion** array of object or I have to navigate to some other component the come back to this component , even navigating to the same component don't work.
I just want to Display the answer on real-time without loading the component again before or after sending **answerObj** to the server.

The structure of allQuestion list of object

> ```
>    allQuestion=[
>     {
>     "questionId":qid,
>     ....,
>     ....,
>     ....,
>     answers:[
>     {
>     "answerId":aid,
>      .....
>      },
>      ]
>      }]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement a real-time system, you can using WebSocket protocol.
In your case, you just want to display the answer without reload the component, just push your new Question object to `allQuestion` intead of navigate.
Like this:

```
setAllQuestion([...allQuestion, { "questionId":qid /* some props */ } ]);
```

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: It's not working , now my component isn't rendering.